# htop does not show all processes

Tags: cpu, htop

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with LXDE desktop environment.

Sometimes my computer runs really slowly and the LXDE its CPU graphic shows a permanent 100% CPU usage. However, when I'm opening htop in a terminal, it says only ~10-30% of CPU is used. Why doesn't htop show all processes so I can see which process is eating my CPU?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to delete this question and ask it on http://askubuntu.com/. Also try to give more information, e.g., how often and when does this happen, also adding a screenshot of `htop` and the CPU graphic might be useful.

Answer (score 10):

By default, htop hides kernel threads like nfsd. To show/hide kernel threads, press uppercase **K** to toggle. htop will save you settings when you exit.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/145707/why-doesnt-htop-display-the-same-processes-as-top

Comment: `htop` was acting weird, it would display a process immediately after I hit `F-4` and entered a search term. But, the processes I am interested in would dissappear after a second.  All of the processes are running as my local, non-root account.  Not sure what was going on, but pressing `K` fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Run `htop` under an administrative account like *root*, you can use `su -` to drop in a *root shell* to execute `htop` or you can instead run `sudo htop` if you have `sudo` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have a multi-core cpu and only one core is at 100%. htop will list activity for *all* cores. Try top instead. If one of your cores is at 100% top will show 100% cpu usage.